# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, exception, object-reference

I have a DataTable called `dtMondayNewsLetter` and when the DT returns no rows. `i.e. Empty`

> it shows an error Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object

**CODE**

```
CurrentDirection = Convert.ToString((from DataRow dr in dtMondayNewsLetter.Rows 
                    where (int)dr["PostID"] == PostID select (string)dr["Direction"])
                           .FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
```

What changes I need to do in above code to eliminate the error.

Comment: Use a `for...loop` instead, much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Null-Coalescing Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). in case that `FirstOrDefault` returns null return empty string.

```
CurrentDirection =
    Convert.ToString(
        (from DataRow dr in dtMondayNewsLetter.Rows
            where (int) dr["PostID"] == PostID
            select (string) dr["Direction"]).FirstOrDefault() ?? "").Trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, query

```
from DataRow dr in dtMondayNewsLetter.Rows 
where (int)dr["PostID"] == PostID 
select (string)dr["Direction"]
```

returns no rows, so `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`.

so you can do a simply `if` to check wheter result is available..

```
var resultString = (from DataRow dr in dtMondayNewsLetter.Rows
                    where (int)dr["PostID"] == PostID 
                    select (string)dr["Direction"])
                   .FirstOrDefault();

if (resultString != null) 
{
    CurrentDirection = resultString.Trim();
}
else
{
    //case, when no rows
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, I would do something like:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtMondayNewsLetter.Rows)
{
    if (dr["PostID"] != DBNull.Value && dr["Direction"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        if ((int)dr["PostID"] == PostID)
        {
            CurrentDirection = dr["Direction"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to be concise by shoving everything into a LINQ statement is not always optimal. In your case, there could be a number of objects, or data, which is `NULL`, thus causing the null reference exception exception.

Inside a one line LINQ statement, it's very difficult to figure out where the NULL object is. Splitting that LINQ statement into a `for...each` loop makes things a lot easier, and achieves the exact same result.

However, if "PostID" and "Direction" are non-nullable (thus no need to use DBNull.Value checks), then use @nopeflow answer, as that is much safer then your current implementation.